# ¿porqué no aparece la imagen que he enlazado a mi archivo html?

Tags: html

Ayuda porfavor ayudenme confirmando si la ruta esta bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código que he puesto

```html
<img src"img/img.jpg"/>
```

Como veran mi carpeta del proyecto se llama alexandrawp y dentro hay una carpeta que se llama paginas principales y dentro de paginas principales esta la carpeta img donde estan las imagenes que quiero enlazar en un documento.html que esta junto a dicha carpeta img

Comment: es `src="./img/img.jpg"` te falto el **=** despues de **src** y pon **./** delante de en nombre de la carpeta **img** es buena practica para especificar que es en ese mismo directorio

Comment: muchas gracias tu repuesta resolvió mi problema

Comment: te lo voy a poner como respuesta, y me la aceptas si puedes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que corregir, luego de **src** le sigue el signo **=** y en la ruta delante del nombre de la carpeta **img**, coloca **./** para espesificar que cargaras de ese mismo directorio. quedaría así:

```
src="./img/img.jpg"
```

Comment: porque tengo que especificar ./ delante cual es la diferencia sino lo pongo ¿y porqué poner eso es mejor?

Comment: es una buena practica usarlo porque por ejemplo en un servidor de nodeJS , se establece una carpeta que tiene las imágenes y sin importar donde este el archivo se dice **/imagenes** y se cargan , pero si se quiere cargar un fichero que se encuentra en la misma ruta se debe usar **./** para poderlo cargar, en conclusión cuando te bayas a referirte al mismo directorio usa ./ , porque en otros contextos puede causarte errores

Comment: Tenia el mismo problema y me lo acabas de resolver. Grande.